# A drawing tablet combined with a dual-monitor system issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, tablet

I have an Aiptek Media Tablet which I've used on my old computer for creating digital art.
For about a month now, I also have a new Quad-core Windows Vista 64-bits system with plenty of disk space and RAM.And the tablet works perfectly on my new system. Then, three weeks ago I also bought a second monitor and turned my setup in a dual-monitor system I didn't use my tablet for the next three weeks so I didn't realise that a dual-monitor will increase the desktop size. In my case, the desktop is now 3520x1200.

The problem now is that my tablet, which supports 4x3 and 16x9 modes is now used for a 3x1 mode. Thus, when drawing a circle on the tablet, it becomes an ellipse on the screen.

I hate that!

So, is there a solution to just limit a tablet to a single monitor? Are there other tablets that are more monitor-aware?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wacom tablets let you map the area on the tablet to a part of the screen. This works perfectly - even on my triple monitor display.

Frankly, any other tablet is really a joke in comparison to the awesome power of a Wacom Intuos.

[image]

Comment: Well, which Wacom tablet would you advise me to use? Would the Intuos4 offer this ioption? (Can't find this information on their site.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all of their Intuos tablets come with the same option. Mine is a slightly older one - I got the "special edition" one in sleek black (love it). The newer ones actually have even more features than mine though.

Comment: Well, I'll give away my current tablet then, and but a Wacom. :) I've heard plenty of good stories about them, so it won't be a waste, although it will cause a small dent in my wallet. :) Brings me back to another question: what to do with the old tablet? ;-)

Comment: ebay          it

Comment: Or use it for target practice. Trust me, once you get an Intuos you'll wonder how you ever lived without it.

Comment: I use a Bamboo and it has the same option.

Answer (score 2):

Wacom tablets combined with [Multiple Monitor Switcher](http://www.yohng.com/tabletswitch.html) work perfectly.

Comment: This works great with my older Graphire3 which doesn't have the nice Intuos control panel. Be advised to read the (short) **Usage** section, it's a bit weird.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but I've just had this problem and only seen people rant on about Wacom, so here's an answer from someone with an **Aiptek 14000u**.

Open this orange icon from your taskbar, and if you don't have it then install aiptek driver
[image: Open this orange icon from your taskbar, and if you don't have it then install aiptek driver]

Click on mapping:
[image: Click on mapping]

Select the monitor you want to use
[[image: Select the monitor you want to use3]

*Don't have to worry about silly pen nibs wearing down every few months, had my aiptek for 6+ years now and JUST had to change the battery for the first time and NEVER had to change the nib.*

Answer (score 0):

In case someone with a Wacom Graphire3 is wondering, here is how (in Windows 7):

[image]

[image]